# React-Native Image Invalid prop 'source' supplied to Image

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I think this is a very annoying bug and feels like there is no solution but I want to share and ask.. I fetch data from server and I get image source from there and I use same Image paths in my mobile react-native App.

I fetch data from server like this :

```
$id = $request->userid;
$items = DB::table('item_user')->where('user_id', $id)->latest()->get();

$new = new Collection();

foreach($items as $item){

$new[] = array(
   ... ,
   'picturePath' => 'require'."('./". $item->picturePath ."')"
);

}

return $new;
```

and in front-end I try to render and I have these images locally. So when I use it locally like :

> require('./images/...')

It works.. but like this its not working :

```
_renderItem = ({item}) => {

        return(
            <View>
               <Image source={ item.picturePath } style={{width: 15, height: 15}}/>
            </View>
        );

    };


    render(){
        return(

        <View>
           <FlatList
                data={this.state.items}
                renderItem={this._renderItem}
                keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
            />
         </View>
        );
    }
```

and I get `error`, How I can solve this :

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'source' supplied to 'Image'.

Comment: react-native can't require static assets at runtime. It has to be at build time.

Comment: is your item.picturePath has full path including the http?

Comment: no it has like require('./images/.../..') and I have these images locally. So when I use it locally like require('./images/...'), it works..

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is not the recommended way to assign dynamically images since React Native must know all your images sources before compiling your bundle.

According to the docs, here's an example of how to load images dynamically:

```
// GOOD
<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />;

// BAD
var icon = this.props.active ? 'my-icon-active' : 'my-icon-inactive';
<Image source={require('./' + icon + '.png')} />;

// GOOD
var icon = this.props.active
  ? require('./my-icon-active.png')
  : require('./my-icon-inactive.png');
<Image source={icon} />;
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html

Hope it helps

Edit:
If you know all the images that could be loaded, you can try something like this:

```
// Create a file containing the references for your images

// images.js
const images = {
  logo: {
    uri: require('your-image-path/logo.png')
  },
  banner: { 
    uri: require('your-image-path/banner.png')
  }
}

export { images }; 


//YourComponent.js
import { images } from 'yourImagesPath';

// for this test, expected to return [ { name: logo }, { name: banner} ]
const imagesFromTheServer = (your fetch);

imagesFromTheServer.map(image => {
  if (!images[image]) {
    return <Text>Image not found</Text>;
  }
  return <Image source={images[image].uri} />; // if image = logo, it will return images[logo] containing the require path as `uri` key
});
```

This is quite hacky but may work.

Let me know if it helped

Comment: I know this but then how I will fetch Image paths from server..? and how I'm going to render hundreds of images?

Comment: You must have all your images mapped and use your condition from the server to load them. Give me 5 minutes, I'll update the answer with an example

Comment: ok It would be perfect, because actually all is ok. I mean this path is a string as it used inside require('...') , but its not working.. I'm waiting thanks!

Comment: I updated the answer. Note it's just an example to express the idea. Hope it helps

Comment: When you know the images going to load, having an array of required images is a good design.

Answer (score 23):

> As the [React Native Documentation says](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html), all your images sources needs to be loaded before compiling your bundle.

Adding a simple image in React Native should be like this:

```
<Image source={require('./path_to_your_image.png')} />
```

Let's say you have this:

```
const slides = {
  car: './car.png',
  phone: '../phone.png',
}
```

Then you pass `slides` as a parameter but still, you won't be able to use it like this (even though logically should work):

```
<Image source={require(props.car)} />
```

**Use `require()` inside the `sildes{}`**

```
const slides = {
  car: require('./car.png'),
  phone: require('../phone.png'),
}
```

And the use it like this:

```
<Image source={props.car} />
```