# To set the dice according to random number generated

Tags: javascript, react-native, dice

i'm working on dice game. i have generated the random number i just want to display the image of dice whatever random number has generated. i just want that when i click on the roll button then random number will be generated. and i want that same image of dice comes while clicking the image

```
    export default class App extends Component {

     constructor(){

    super();

    this.state={

   // This is our Default number value
   NumberHolder : 1

   }
   }

   GenerateRandomNumber=()=>
   {

   var RandomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1 ;

   this.setState({

    NumberHolder : RandomNumber

    })
     }

    render() {
    return (

   <View style={styles.MainContainer} >

   <Text style={{marginBottom: 10, fontSize: 20}}> 
   {this.state.NumberHolder}</Text>

   <Button title="Roll again" onPress={this.GenerateRandomNumber} />

   </View>

   );
   }
   }

  const styles = StyleSheet.create(
  {
  MainContainer: {
 flex: 1,
 justifyContent: 'center',
 alignItems: 'center',
 }

 });
```

i just want that die image come whichever random number has generated. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can store name of each image as the number(image for number 1 should be saved by 1.jpg). In this way you can create a component to add image as pass the number as prop

Comment: @ShauryaVardhanSingh i have saved in images but i don't know how to open the image on random number can you please show me some code for that it will be great help

Comment: I made a little [snack](https://snack.expo.io/BkkNIODlS) that you can take a look at, hope that helps :)

Comment: this is helpful but just one doubt i'm having images of dice downloaded but how can i shuffle those images. like i have number 6 came then 6th number should be open how can i do that.

Comment: That's pretty much what happens on that snack :)

Comment: no in that snack all the images are coming from backened url but my images are present in the app itself how can i do that?

Comment: @alishaxyz look at the commented part in that snack :)

Comment: @VilleKoo i did this              source={require(`./images_${this.state.NumberHolder}.png`)}

Comment: but i'm getting  error: bundling failed: Error: App.js:Invalid call at line 44: require("./images_" + this.state.NumberHolder + ".png")

Comment: Hi, yeah you should have backticks ( ` ) around that `./images_${this.stateNumberHolder}.png` . Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: yes i have done this `./images_${this.state.NumberHolder}.png`

Comment: i'm getting error i forgot to add backticks in comment but in code i have added them

Comment: in images folder i have added all the dice images.

Comment: @VilleKoo do you have idea about this

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50334238/react-native-image-invalid-prop-source-supplied-to-image),  it will explain why `require` is not working in your scenario

Comment: after this code i'm getting undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.active')
<unknown>
 this error

Comment: @VilleKoo i have more than two images that condition is applied to two images only i have six images.

Comment: @VilleKoo can you plzz see this one last time.

Comment: @alishaxyz checkout the updated [snack](https://snack.expo.io/r1MoTTdeH)

Comment: @VilleKoo it's working fine what if i want to show two dice and getting two different dice

Answer (score 0):

You can save the images according to the number and then retrieve them

```
let randomNumber = 5
// send your randomNumber as a prop to Image Component
<Image imageid = {randomNumber} >
```

Code for image component

```
import React from "react"

class Image extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="diceImage">
               <img src = `${this.props.imageid}.jpg` alt="an image of the dice">
           </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Image
```

if you have images in the same folder simply provide the name in src else provide the path