# Dynamic file names in react native require()

Tags: node.js, reactjs, database, react-native, augmented-reality

We're working on an app that will allow users to store templates with images on them, and pull those templates up later. This is for an AR environment using Viro on React Native.

We're trying to dynamically load an image into the component, and receiving errors when we require the filepath, which has been set to a variable:

```
const exampleUri = '/some/uri'
render() {
  return(       
    <Viro3DObject
    source={require(exampleUri)}
    />)
}
```

The URI for the source prop has to be dynamic, as the URIs are pulled from a Database.
We've tried storing the entire request in the database (in models/element.js):

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../db');
const Element = db.define('element', {
sourceViro3DObject: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
  }
});

sourceViro3DObject: `require('../../assets/emoji_heart/emoji_heart.vrx')`
```

When we called it in the React Native class component:

```
  getObjectData = async () => {
    try {
      const {data} = await axios.get(`/api/elements/${this.props.elementId}`)
      this.setState({sourceViro3DObject: data.sourceViro3DObject})
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.getObjectData()
  }
```

But this simply sets state.sourceViro3DObject to a string:

```
'require('../../assets/emoji_heart/emoji_heart.vrx')'
```

We've tried setting the filepath directly to state as a string:

`state.sourceViro3DObject = '../../assets/emoji_heart/emoji_heart.vrx'`

and then call require on it:

`require(this.state.sourceViro3DObject)`

and received the following error:

```
Invalid prop `source` supplied to `Viro3DObject`
```

We've seen recommendations of storing the URIs in an object, but that can't work for us as we don't know what image is going to be used until it's pulled from the database. We can't hard-code them anywhere.

We'd appreciate any help with this!

Comment: just curious, have you tried hitting the backend/db in a browser to see what you get back? what do you get if you log ```const {data} = await axios.get(`/api/elements/${this.props.elementId}`)```?

Comment: also, see if this helps, if you have confirmed that you you are getting the expected results from the api/db: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50334238/react-native-image-invalid-prop-source-supplied-to-image

Comment: Hey @HolyMoly! We did console.log that. It comes back as a string 'require(/whatever/uri)' (when we store it with the require call). This is read as only a string, so 'require' doesn't actually get called.

Comment: Sorry, posted too soon! We did see the other solution you linked to, but it also has a hard-coded aspect:
// GOOD
var icon = this.props.active
  ? require('./my-icon-active.png')
  : require('./my-icon-inactive.png');
<Image source={icon} />;
So you do have to know what the possible URIs would be, whereas we're trying to allow for a case where you don't know the URI. So it's a great workaround for specified URIs, but it doesn't quite achieve our goal.